# WASD not syncing with the camera, so forward is the same direction no matter which way i face

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have 2 scripts for my game. a look script and a player move script. I will post them both below. I can rotate my player normally but when I move the keys push me in the same direction no matter which way I'm facing. for example w can push me backward, left, right, or forward depending on which way I face. I have tried many different things I found online but still can't make it work. Sorry there are a lot of nonsense comments I tried saving many of my attempts to refer back to them.

```
     `public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
   {
public Transform Player;

public bool IsGrounded;
public CharacterController controller;
public float Speed = 12f;
Vector3 velocity;
public float gravity =-9.9f;
public Transform GroundCheck;
public float GroundDistance = .4f;
public LayerMask groundMask;
public float jumpheight = 2f;
private Vector3 rotation;
private float mouseSensitivity;
private float xRotation;
private float yRotation;



void Update()
{
    IsGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(GroundCheck.position, GroundDistance, groundMask);

    if(IsGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
    {
        velocity.y = -2f;
    }
    this.rotation = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") *       
  Time.deltaTime);
    Vector3 move = this.rotation;
    //move = this.transform.InverseTransformDirection(move);
    controller.Move(move * Speed);
    //this.transform.Rotate(this.rotation);
     /*
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") *Time.deltaTime, 0,   
  Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*Time.deltaTime);
    this.transform.Rotate(move);
    //transform.TransformDirection(move * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    //float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    //float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    //Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    controller.Move(move * Speed);
   
    //controller.transform.TransformDirection(move);
    // Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    //move = transform.TransformDirection(move);
    //controller.Move(move * Speed * Time.deltaTime);

    /*Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward*z;
           controller.Move(move * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
 //controller.transform.TransformDirection(move);
 controller.transform.TransformDirection(move);
   */ //controller.Move(move * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(velocity*Time.deltaTime);
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpheight * -2 * gravity);
    }
}

 }

  public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
 {
float xRotation = 0f;
float yRotation = 0f;

public Transform Player;
public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity *Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
    yRotation += mouseX;
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0f);
    transform.TransformDirection(xRotation, yRotation, 0f);
    Player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
  
}
 }
```

I want to move in the direction I am facing but instead the wasd keys push me in the same direction regardless of rotation

Answer (score 0):

In your movement script multiply this line with transform.forward

> this.rotation*speed